# Double strings that are the same are being posted

Tags: php

So, I am trying to make a "quote" system for my comment area.
Like, if someone were to quote someone else, it SHOULD appear like:

```
>quoted text
```

and the quote text would be green.
I got the green text to work, but my issue now is that when the post is quoted, the un-quoted version also appears, like:

```
>quote
quote
```

My PHP:

```
<?php

include 'db.php';
$comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($comment))
{
$p_id = $row['id'];
$c_name = $row['name'];
$c_email = $row['email'];
$c_sub = $row['sub'];
$c_post = $row['post'];
$c_post = str_ireplace('>', "<span class=\"gtext\"><blockquote>$c_post</blockquote></span>", $c_post);
echo "<span class=\"sub\">$c_sub</span> <span class=\"postname\">$c_name</span> No.$p_id &nbsp; \n";
//echo "[a href=\"index.php?reply=$id\">Reply</a>]";
echo "<blockquote>$c_post</blockquote>";
echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the original post is being modified when it's quoted?

Comment: No, it can really be anything I guess. Whenever '>quoted text' is there, it just appears as:
>text

text

Comment: look at how your replace is working. http://codepad.viper-7.com/TOrVSh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `str_ireplace(...)` line replaces the `>` character with the whole quoted text, but the original text is not cut off.

One way would be to use `preg_replace(...)` like this:

```
$post = preg_replace('/^>(.*)$/m', '<span class="gtext"><blockquote>\{1}</blockquote></span>', $post);
```

This will match the `>` **and** the following text, and replace it with just the text wrapped inside tags.

Another way would work without regular expressions:

```
if(0 === strpos('>', $post)) {
    $post = substr($post, 1);
    $post = '<span class="gtext"><blockquote>' . $post . '</blockquote></span>';
}
```

This will check for the `>` character at position 0, trim it off, and wrap the post in the tags.
This only works if the whole `$post` is either a single qoute or not.
The `preg_replace(...)` method will replace any occurence of the `>` character properly (matches text until newline).
The `m` modifier used in the expression will make it check every single line instead of the string as a whole.

Comment: Thank you very much Lukas! It works, and I just have to finish styling it up. Thank you very much! I should of stated I was new to PHP as well..

Answer (score 0):

Your str_ireplace call looks for a '>' and replaces it with `"<span class=\"gtext\"><blockquote>$c_post</blockquote></span>"`, so you still have the quote following it.

To rectify this, you could then look for the next newline after '>', store it, delete the contents before the new line and after the '>', THEN call the str_ireplace call with the second argument instead referencing your newly stored value in the second argument.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php